# Upright greeks in Asana-math?

Tags: xetex, unicode-math

I'm using

- XeTeX,
- unicode-math with
- Asana-math.otf

and required to make all greek letters in math -- upright. Asana-math seem to have upright greek letters:

[image]

(on the contrary I can't find italic greek letters in the file). But if I call `\mathnormal` I don't get any output at all:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} % enagles loading of OpenType fonts
\usepackage{polyglossia} % support for languages

% fonts:
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text} % without this XeLaTeX won't turn "--" into dashes
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

% math:
\usepackage{amsmath} % for some math commands/symbols
\usepackage{amssymb} % for commands like \gg and \ll
\usepackage{mathtools} % for things like Vmatrix*
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools} % for advanced typesetting like multiline equations, and the likes.
\usepackage{unicode-math} % to use unicode in the formulas -- to improve readability of sources
\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf} % it is important to have this line after the amsmath, mathtools and other maths

\begin{document}

Test upright greeks:
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
  α & = & \mathnormal{α} \;.
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

I get no upright letter at all:

[image]

Is there a way I can get upright greeks with unicode-math, Asana-math font?

**Edit**:

I thought maybe it's a font issue. So I tried `Latin Modern Math`:

```
\setmathfont[Path=fnt/]{latinmodern-math.otf}
```

but no luck!

**Edit 2**:

In my complex setup I get issues with sqrt and few other symbols -- when I specify range as in egreg solution. I added expression with sqrt to egreg's solution to reproduce the error:

[image]

As You see I can't reproduce the sqrt issue, but I get box on the second line.

**Edit 3**:

After I upgraded unicode-math to `0.7e` I can reproduce the sqrt issue:

[image]

Here's a [full log](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/61989972/Misc/test.log). I read it and I noted:

```
Missing character: There is no ϵ in font [Asana-Math.otf]/ICU:script=math;lang
uage=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ≫ in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ≪ in font cmr10!
```

lines. So probably have outdated `Asana-Math.otf`.

**Edit 4**:

After I updated `Asana-Math` the epsilon issue is resolved, but not the sqrt one:

[image]

And I still get:

```
Missing character: There is no ≫ in font cmr10!
```

What is that `cmr10`?

Comment: With `unicode-math` version 0.7e and Asana-Math.otf version 000.949 I get correct output both for epsilon and the square root. Don't load `amssymb`; I get correct output without it and the input `$a≫\theta$`

Comment: I don't load `amssymb` -- I started from Your solution.

Comment: It's some weird bug in my set up. I wanted to note that it's note that important because when I'm not using `range` I seem to have everything working.

Comment: What output do you get from `otfinfo -v $(kpsewhich Asana-Math.otf)`?

Comment: It's `000.907`. But I'm using newest version: `\setmathfont[Path=fnt/,math-style=french]{Asana-Math.otf}` and that one is: `000.949`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a new math alphabet that uses the `math-style=french` option for the Greek lowercase letters:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} % enagles loading of OpenType fonts
\usepackage{polyglossia} % support for languages

% fonts:
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Ligatures=TeX} % without this XeLaTeX won't turn "--" into dashes
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

% math:
\usepackage{amsmath} % for some math commands/symbols
\usepackage{mathtools} % for things like Vmatrix*
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools} % for advanced typesetting like multiline equations, and the likes.
\usepackage{unicode-math} % to use unicode in the formulas -- to improve readability of sources
\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf} % it is important to have this line after the amsmath, mathtools and other maths
\setmathfont[math-style=french,range={"3B1-"3C9,"1D6FC-"1D71B}]{Asana-Math.otf}
\begin{document}

Test upright greeks: $αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω+xyz$

Test: $\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon+xyz$

Test: $a\gg\theta$ $\beta\ll y$

\end{document}
```

Note that `amssymb` is not needed: all symbols it defines are covered by Unicode math. I've added both the ranges for Greek lowercase and math Greek lowercase for greater safety.

[image]

Comment: Thank You very much. A question though: `"3B1-"3C9` are lowercase greeks; but who are `"1D6FC-"1D71B`?

Comment: @Adobe They are the "math lowercase Greek" range; for instance `U+1D6FC` is MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL ALPHA. So, if you happen to copy-paste a symbol, you'd get the correct upright letter.

Comment: If I specify range I break root and many other symbols. If I don't specify range -- I don't break anything and still have upright greeks.

Comment: @Adobe I don't understand. What's broken with my code?

Comment: I've update the question and added a screenshot there. I can't reproduce the sqrt issue I'm facing with my set up, but I did get other font issue. See the screenshot.

Comment: @Adobe Make sure you have a fully updated TeX distribution; what are you using?

Comment: `This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (TeX Live 2012/Debian) (format=xelatex 2013.4.26)`. What is Yours?

Comment: The version of XeTeX is the same. Maybe it's `unicode-math`; mine is `2013/03/16 v0.7d`

Comment: You were right that I had outdated `unicode-math`. After I upgraded it to latest `0.7e` -- I can reproduce the sqrt issue (see the screenshot in the OP).